# Install Failed Insufficient storage amplify

Tags: android, flutter, virtual-machine, aws-amplify

I have got this error when I first run my app, I tried creating a new phone but still get the same error.[image]

Comment: have you check the size on disk when you create new device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application couldn't install because your device storage is too small. Even if your app is not that big, you have to keep in mind that in debug mode, your app is a lot bigger than in release mode.

Open Android Studio.

1. Open AVD Manager on the top right corner.
2. Go on the edit icon of your device.

[screenshot for step 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7EA3.png)

3. Then Show advanced settings.
4. Scroll down to Memory and Storage section.
5. Increase Internal Storage

[screenshot for step 3 and 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7wQA.png)

6. Click on Finish
7. Restart your Android Emulator

If your computer do not have enough storage, try to reduce your app size, which is a good practice.
Here is a link to Flutter documentation that will show you how to analyse your app size and how you can reduce it.